# Way to have repeating sequence of animations till interrupted?

Tags: jquery, animation

Is there a way to do the following in jQuery:

1. Animate DIV to `left: -200px; top: -200px`
2. Animate DIV to `left: 0px; top: -400px`
3. Animate DIV to `left: -200px; top: -600px`
4. Go to 1, repeat till some user event interrupts

Comment: Yes, it's doable. What did you try and what problems did you encounter?

Comment: Just wondering if there was a better way than doing it like Simon's answer (which I've already tried and works).

Comment: haha, its a complete diffrent question, you should provied what you have done and ask how to make it cleaner ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't quite follow what exact dimensions you wanted, but you can fill in the values you want.  Here's the general idea.  jQuery animations go in a queue and are naturally chained one after the other so you can just fire them all off and it will queue them up and then use the completion function on the last one to start it over again like this:

```
function go() {
    $("#box")
        .animate({left: "100px", top: "0"}, 1000)
        .animate({left: "400px", top: "0"}, 1000)
        .animate({left: "400px", top: "400px"}, 2000)
        .animate({left: "100px", top: "400px"}, 2000, go);

}

go();

$("#stop").click(function() {
    $("#box").stop(true);
});

$("#start").click(go);
```

You can stop the animation at any time by calling the jQuery `.stop(true)` method on the animating object.  Here's a working demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/PnzQ9/

Answer (score 1):

This will work, but you will not see anything in http://jsfiddle.net/rQCz7/3/ couse its outside the viewport. Maybe you get some hint about how to complete it.

```
var div = $("div");

function animate(){
    div.animate({left: -200, top: -200}, 5000)
        .animate({left: 0, top: -400}, 5000)
        .animate({left: -200, top: -600}, 5000, animate);
}
animate();
```

Comment: Yeah, this is what I have currently. Works OK, just wondering if there was a slightly more elegant solution.

Comment: You don't need to nest these in completion functions.  Animations are naturally chained together one after the other.

Answer (score 1):

And to stop the animation with a certain user event, you can do, for instance:

```
$('#stop_link').click(function() {
    $('#box').stop(true, true);
    return false;
});
```

For more information about the stop method, go to http://api.jquery.com/stop/